# Early 2000s sci-fi book where the main character investigates a suspected meteor, and discovers an alien craft on his heavily forested colony world

Tags: story-identification, books, space

I'm looking for the title of a science fiction book. I believe it would have been pre 2010.

I believe the book is part of a trilogy. The setting is a heavily forested colony world, dotted with the occasional small village or town. The main character's profession was that of a game warden or something involving forestry.

Over the course of the story, the main character investigates a suspected meteor, and discovers an alien spacecraft. He then tries to warn the rest of the colony of the alien creatures. I believe the next book in series involves the colonists trying to fight off the threat.

If I remember correctly, the cover art for the books followed a progression as well. The first book showed a dense forest at night, with an aurora I think. The second book had almost the same art, but with a comet depicted in the sky.

That's about all I remember, unfortunately. And help rediscovering these books would be greatly appreciated! Thank you.